# JVM memory + dose heap size Xmx values have impact on consuming memory

Tags: linux, rhel, process, java

we have linux redhat machines with service ( service is based on java )

for now service consume `1.5G` memory , and the heap size set to `Xmx2G`

let say we increase the heap size to `Xmx10G`

dose this change have impact on consuming memory on the service?

or service should be use the same memory as was before the heap size change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you size your JVM well. And you do not need to extend the size of heap. The wise method is to monitor this JVM and see if you really need more memory, check the maps of objects, old, new generation and so on.

About your answer you (probably) will not see significant change of used memory if you extend the size of heap.